# Why update softwares before upgrading to next version?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am using ubuntu 13.10 now.

I am willing to update my os into 14.04 after it's release. Is it needed to update my softwares before updating to 14.04. If it so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to update your software, The Software Updater will do that for you automatically.

Except if you are using some 3rd party PPA. Those may be disabled after upgrade and software from that repo may not be available if the author has not created package for new ubuntu version.

[image: 13.10 upgrade]

Comment: What if I' m upgrading from USB DRIVE. Without Internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the installed packages then go for an update else you don't need to update the packages.

If you don't update the packages then you won't get the new features implemented in the new package version.

No, It isn't compulsory to update  the packages before  upgrading to another Ubuntu version.

Comment: What if I' m upgrading from USB DRIVE. Without Internet connection?

Comment: If you have a separate home partition,You will lost only your installed applications while upgrading from USB drive.